# How to integrate one function into another one

Tags: python, range

As an exercise for a class I am taking I have to write some functions and then integrate one into the other, I have written two working functions so far one that takes an an integer y and tell you whether that integer is a leap year and another that will take an integer y (year) and an integer n (month) and will tell you how many days are in that month. What I want to do is integrate the first function into the second one so that if you input February on a leap year it will tell you it has 29 days.

Here is the code I have written thus far;

```
def isLeapYear(y):
    if y % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if y % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if y % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and

```
def daysIn (y,n):
    import sys

    d = int(0)
    months = ["Notuary", "January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May",       "June", "July", "August", "September",
              "October", "November", "December"]

    if n == 0:
        print("This is a fake month")
        sys.exit()

    if n == 1 or n == 3 or n == 5 or n == 7 or n == 8 or n == 10 or n == 12:
        d = 31

   if n == 2 and (y % 4 != 0):
        d = 28

    if n == 2 and (y % 4 == 0):
        print("Febuary has 29 days this year as it is a leap year")
        sys.exit()

    if n == 4 or n == 6 or n == 9 or n == 11:
        d = 30

    print(months[n], "has", d, "days in it")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW, your `daysIn` function could be made a lot more compact using sets or lists in your month length tests, but I guess you might not have learned about those yet. But the `d = int(0)` near the top of the function is a bit pointless: there's no need to convert zero to an integer, it's _already_ an integer, so you can just do `d = 0`. Also, it's unusual to put an `import` statement inside a function. Just put it at the top of your script

Answer (score 0):

You should use your `isLeapYear` function to determine whether to return 28 or 29 days from the `daysIn` function.

```
if n == 2:
   if isLeapYear(y):
       print("It's a leap year!")
       d = 29
   else 
       d = 28
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import sys
def isLeapYear(y):
    if y % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if y % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if y % 4 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def daysIn (y,n, func):
    d = int(0)
    months = ["Notuary", "January", "Febuary", "March", "April",      "May","June", "July", "August", "September","October", "November", "December"]
    if n == 0:
        print("This is a fake month")
        sys.exit()
    if n == 1 or n == 3 or n == 5 or n == 7 or n == 8 or n == 10 or n == 12:
        d = 31
    if n == 2 and func(y):
        d = 28
    if n == 2 and func(y):
        print("Febuary has 29 days this year as it is a leap year")
        sys.exit()
    if n == 4 or n == 6 or n == 9 or n == 11:
        d = 30
    print(months[n], "has", d, "days in it")
daysIn(1996, 2, isLeapYear)
```

In python, function is also an object. So you can pass it into another function as paramater.

Comment: This is a very confusing way to write this.

Comment: sorry i don't under stand what you mean. You mean my indent error?

Comment: I mean the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just call 1 function from inside the other.

For example:

```
def daysIn (y,n):
    import sys

    isleap = isLeapYear(y)

    # SNIP

    print(months[n], "has", d, "days in it")
    print("Is {} a leap year? {}".format(y, isleap))
```